# Can I automatically deploy same Azure function code multiple times to different functions?

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-functions

My scenario is that I have an Azure function that executes some logic.
We are scaling the system and making it self-serve where each partner can clone the function, change the configs, and deploy to a new Azure function.
Since the function's logic will be exactly the same and the only difference is in the config files, I'm wondering if there is a way to let partners only add a new config file and then the function logic gets deployed to separate functions, 1 function for each config file. I need to do that because cloning the same code over and over sounds messy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Functions to deploy your code continuously by using [source control integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies#source-control).
It enables a workflow in which a code update triggers deployment to Azure.

For continuous deployments of azure functions check [Deployment requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment#requirements-for-continuous-deployment).

Comment: Can I use this to say if file1 changed deploy to function1, file2 to function2...etc.? and how to tell the deployment which config file to pick?

Comment: Could you please refer this links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54151745/how-can-i-deploy-multiple-copies-of-an-azure-function-with-different-parameters ,& https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57079549/deploying-multiple-function-under-same-azure-function-app-not-working